# Special Characters in routeparams executing controller twice in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

How can I pass keyword (containing special characters) as a $routeParam to AngularJS App?

`$routeProvider.when('/search/:keyword', {templateUrl:'someURL', controller:SearchCtrl})`

This **keyword** can contain special characters.

So, I did encodeURIComponent to the "keyword" before redirecting to this page.

When this "keyword" has some special characters such as "$, @, &, comma" etc. then the controller is executing twice.

EX:
If the keyword has '$' symbol,
the **Controller**

- Executes 1st with encoded form of that symbol (#/search/%24)
- Executes 2nd with actual symbol (#/search/$)

This does not happen in the case of carat('^') symbol.

Am I missing out somewhere or Is my approach incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a workaround to deal with this kind of scenario:

```
utils.encodeUriQuery = function (val) {
        return encodeURIComponent(val).
            replace(/%40/gi, '@').
            replace(/%3A/gi, ':').
            replace(/%24/g, '$').
            replace(/%2C/gi, ',').
            replace(/%26/gi, '&').
            replace(/%3D/gi, '=').
            replace(/%2B/gi, '+');
    }
```

Calling the above function before I pass the search keyword to the URL

```
$window.location.href = "/#/search/" + utils.encodeUriQuery(searchKeyword);
```

NOTE: utils is a factory.

Comment: It's not so clear answer. You also should provide what's utils because I'm getting Reference error. Please improve your answer

Comment: It was just an idea, where utils is a factory, and yes there was a typo in my second snippet, thank you.

Comment: Thanks, now it has sense :-)